# Counting This Probability

Tags: probability

I'm working with two 20 sided die. Consider the product of these two rolls.
Let us say that the probability of getting a particular roll is proportional
to the product of the upper-facing numbers on the two dice. Note that within
one product, the probabilities of each possible way I can get that product
are the same, i.e. if $k$ is the sum , $P(k=4) = P(\text{ two 2's}) +
P(\text{one 1 and one 4}),$ where $P(\text{ two 2's}) =
P(\text{one 1 and one 4}).$ I want to find the probability that the product
will be even. I understand what we are looking for is
$$\sum_{1 \leq k \leq 400, 2\mid k} P(k)$$
Where $k$ is the product of the two rolls. I also see how I can formalize that
$P(k) = kP(1)$ given our proportionality argument. That being said, I could
use some help trying to fully define this probabilistic model.

Comment: If both dice are fair (i.e., each of the twenty numbers from $1$ to $20$ show up equally often on either die), then the probability that the product is even is equal to the probability that neither die comes up odd, which is $3/4$.  If you mean something different (especially in "the probability of getting a particular roll is proportional to the product of the upper-facing numbers on the two dice"), please clarify.

Comment: For instance, it is impossible to have $P(23) = 23P(1)$, since $P(23) = 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to normalize the probabilities, to find the sum of all the products. The sum of the rolls of one die is $\frac 12(20)(21)=210$ so the sum of products is $210^2=44100$. The chance of getting a product $k$ is $mk/44100$ where $m$ is the number of ordered ways to make a product of $k$. For example, the chance of $36$ is $7 \cdot 36/44100$ as there are $7$ rolls with a product of $36-2+18,3+12,4+9,6+6,9+4,12+3,18+2$

Comment: To answer the OP's question using this interpretation, note that we can determine the probability of each result by assuming that the dice are independent, with each face coming up with probability proportional to the die value.  That is, for a single die, $P(k) = k/210$.  In that case, the probability that a given die comes up odd is $1-110/210 = 10/21$, and the probability that both are odd is $100/441$; therefore the probability that the product is even is $341/441$.

Comment: @Brian: that is right. OP asked about odd, but also more generally. Thanks for the addition.